# how to pass document id of orbeon form to webservice?

Tags: orbeon

I have a restful web service to generate a barcode from the document id and return barcode as image. I want to load that barcode image into Orbeon Forms. So I create an image in the form and I want to load the image from the REST service to an image tag.

```
<control-95>http://localhost:8080/formservice/services/detail/barcode/{xxf:document-id()}</control-95>
```

It won't retrieve the document id.

How can I pass document id as request parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a calculated value (from Control Settings → Formulas) instead. Something like this:

```
concat(
    'http://localhost:8080/formservice/services/detail/barcode/',
    xxf:document-id()
)
```